# How Can I Read Cookies Coming Back in the Response to a RESTEasy Client?

Tags: java, rest, cookies, resteasy

I am using a RESTEasy Proxy client, and instantiating it with the following code.

```
final ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
final ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(pUrl);
mClient = target.proxy(FooClientProxy.class);
```

where `FooClientProxy` is my proxy interface.

`FooClientProxy` defines a `login` method, as follows

```
@POST
@Path("/foo/login/{username}/{password}")
public abstract void login(@PathParam("username") String pUsername, @PathParam("password") String pPassword);
```

On logging in, with `mClient.login(pUsername, pPassword);`, I would like to see what cookies I have got back in the response.

Is there a way I can interrogate the proxy client to read the cookies in the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is your login method `void`? If you would return a `Response` you could read the Cookie like this:

```java
mClient = target.proxy(FooClientProxy.class);
Response response = mClient.login(user, pw);
NewCookie cookie = response.getCookies().get(cookieName);
```

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was missing. I do have another problem now - when I read the response, all subsequent calls using the same proxy client failed with an error that my connection is still open. What is the safe way to close the connection once the Cookie has been read?

Comment: Use `response.close()` when you've read everything you need from the response and `client.close()` when you won't do more requests..

Answer (score 1):

I think you can inject the HttpSession request where you should be able to access the cookies:

```
@POST
public String someRestCall(Postdata postdata, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
  System.out.println(request.getCookies());
}
```

Respectively for your case

```
@POST
@Path("/foo/login/{username}/{password}")
public abstract void login(@PathParam("username") String pUsername, @PathParam("password") String pPassword,  @Context HttpServletRequest request);
```

I am not 100% sure since I can not test it here, but I am pretty sure :-)

Comment: Thanks. But my code is on the client. I am using the RESTEasy client to call a REST service. In my client, I want to see which cookies have been set by the server